# use rest api written for angular js in android app

Tags: java, android, angularjs, rest

I need to know if I write Rest API in JAVA using Spring framework and I will be using it in angular js front end, is it possible to use the same API's for Andriod app later. Is it a good to use same api's for both web and app, I have no idea about android development, please help.

Comment: You have a good answer below, and I think you might like to check out NativeScript (NativeScript.org) with Angular integration... I'm playing with that right now to make an app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your API is RESTful, and by that I mean at least stateless and resource based. Then yeah, it doesn't matter what program you're requesting data from.

If your are able to process the response into your front end (reading the format, etc). It'll be fine. Just make sure your API's endpoints work correctly and are configured to handle the request your programs will be using to communicate with your API (most of the times these are http requests)

Comment: Great thanks, I also wanted to know if its good to use same API's for web and app, as I am not sure if its gonna affect the performance and speed for app or any other issues.

Comment: It won't  as long as both you front end and back end code (your API) are well written. Other than that, there shouldn't be any other issues.